# How to say "for"

Tags: words

I will use a specific example.
I was trying to write "My love for you is hurting me."

"私の愛ために貴方は私を傷つけている。" Is what I came up with, however, I am unsure about the usage of "ために" in this situation.

And if it is incorrect, what would be the correct way to say "for"?

Comment: 愛ため is definitely wrong both for syntactic and semantic reasons. I think that 私のあなたへの愛 would be a literal translation of "my love for you", but I doubt its elegance.

Comment: ために was the only thing I can find for "for" in my dictionary, so I had to try with that, heh. 
I see. Well, elegance doesn't really concern me, so it is a viable choice- I suppose it can be used in other situations where "my x for you" is being stated, right?

Comment: When you use `ために` with a noun, you usually put the particle `の` between them, like `愛のために`.

Comment: ために is more like "for the purpose of" or "for the sake of". For expressions like "my love for you", you need something closer to "towards" (which could be へ or への as others suggested).

Comment: I see. 
Ah, so that's why "へ" is added.
Thank you, both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like user1205935 said, 私のあなたへの愛、 or あなたへの私の愛、 or あなたに対する私の愛 seems to be the translation. In my experience, things like "for you" get turned into statements of possession. The only other case I can think of is when thanking someone for something- you don't even use の, it just turns into 何何～ **を** ありがとう。
為に is more along the lines of for the purpose, implying some end in mind- which in this case doesn't make sense.

Comment: あなたへの私の愛 sounds the best to me, and that answers my primary question, but I must ask this too- why is "へ" added? (And much gratitude for answering my question.)